# $\mathbb{R}$ with co-countable topology is not a topological group

Tags: geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

In a problem sheet we're asked to show that $G=\mathbb{R}$ with co-countable topology is not a topological group because

$$f:G \times G \longrightarrow G$$
$$(x,y) \longmapsto x+y$$

is not continuous. But my argument is that it's continuous, and I can't see what's wrong with my argument:

Let $U \subseteq G$ be open, then $U = \mathbb{R} \backslash V$ for some countable $V$. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
f^{-1}(U)
&=& \{ (x,y) \mid x + y \notin V \} \\
&=& \bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{R}} \{ (x,y) \mid x \notin V - y \}
\end{eqnarray}

and we see that $\{ (x,y) \mid x \notin V - y \}$ is homeomorphic to $U$ by the obvious $(x,y) \longmapsto x + y$, so it's an open set. So $f^{-1}(U)$ is a union of open sets, hence it's open.

Comment: Think about what are open sets of $G \times G$.

Answer (score 1):

In general is not true that  if $A\subset X$ is an open set and $B\subset Y$ is a subset of $Y$ such that there exists an homeomorphism between $A$ and $B$ than $B $ is an open set of $Y$

In you case you have that

$f^{-1}(U)=\mathbb{R}^2 / f^{-1}(V)$

But

$f^{-1}(V)=\{(x,v-x): x\in\mathbb{R}, v\in   
V\}$

and his cardinality is

$|f^{-1}(V)|=|\mathbb{R}|\cdot |V|= |\mathbb{R}|$

because $V$ is cauntable.

Than $f^{-1}(U)$ is not a co-countable set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so is not an open set with respect to product Topology induced by co-countable Topology of $\mathbb{R}$
because this product Topology is the co-countable Topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the open sets with respect to this Topology are only the co-countable sets.